# How to create a listing of Social networks' posts with Drupal

Tags: drupal, twitter, instagram

I want to achieve something like this: http://curatorsofsweden.com with DRUPAL

Here different people post over the same twitter-Account for one week. The Twitter-stream is published on the Website and you can also „time travel“ via the archive to see what which people posted in which week/days.

I want to achieve the same with DRUPAL and with a Twitter AND Instagram Account (and maybe FB too). My Idea is to import those streams with the feeds-module to treat the posts as DRUPAL-content. This way is more flexible to work with the content afterwards. But how to "automatically" map this to different users (or maybe treat a user as own content-type instead of normal DRUPAL-user?)?

What modules - or combination of modules - would you use to realize this? Im open for any suggestion!

Thanks 
St.

Comment: Drupal has a core module called aggregator. You could use that. Stackoverflow is not the place to look for tutorials. You could obviously use the Feeds module. Search google for a feeds module tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the view/config page of the feed to include a "user reference" using terms or taxonomy. This *might* require using a custom hook_form_alter to tweak it a bit.